# how to do and show results of 2 subqueries in php web services and generate a json encode

Tags: php, json, web-services, mysqli

I'm doing a web service but I need to get data from two different tables taking into account the result of a query in a relational table

How can I make 2 queries to two different tables taking into account a 3 query to obtain the data of those queries?

I have a relational table in which I keep the id's and I need to make a query of that table and then make two queries to two different tables to get the data and show them together in a json to be able to use it

example:

```
$ query1 = "select * from family where ID = 2";

while ($ query1) {
$ consult2 = "select * from adults where son = $ query1 ['ID']";

$ consult3 = "select * from siblings where son = $ query1 ['ID']";
}
```

my code for the query is this, is in PHP:

```
require 'Database.php';

class Union {
    function __construct(){
    }

   public static function getById($id_vehiculo){
        // Consulta del vehiculo
        $consulta = "SELECT id_relacion, id_operador, id_vehiculo FROM uniontaxioperador WHERE id_vehiculo = ?";    

       try {
            // Preparar sentencia
            $comando = Database::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($consulta);
            // Ejecutar sentencia preparada
            $comando->execute(array($id_vehiculo));
            // Capturar primera fila del resultado
            $row = $comando->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $row;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            // Aquí puedes clasificar el error dependiendo de la excepción
            // para presentarlo en la respuesta Json
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

and to show the json is this:

```
require 'WS_consulta.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {

    if (isset($_GET['id_vehiculo'])) {

        // Obtener parámetro id_vehiculo
        $parametro = $_GET['id_vehiculo'];

        // Tratar retorno
        $retorno = Union::getById($parametro);


        if ($retorno) {

            $union["estado"] = "1";
            $union["id_relacion"] = $retorno;
            // Enviar objeto json de la union
            print json_encode($union);
        } else {
            // Enviar respuesta de error general
            print json_encode(
                array(
                    'estado' => '2',
                    'mensaje' => 'No se obtuvo el registro'
                )
            );
        }

    } else {
        // Enviar respuesta de error
        print json_encode(
            array(
                'estado' => '3',
                'mensaje' => 'Se necesita un identificador'
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to learn what and how you do a join query. Looks here for example https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: hello, i already read this w3 example but don't solve may question, maybe i need a json array, but i don't have idea how to make it, can you help me?